# electron use post request fails

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, electron

I am trying to turn my node app into a desktop using Electron. In my current code I use a "POST" request and the res.send() to return data back from my node script. Express handles the end points.

However, when I try and use the same code with Electron I get

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I have spent lots of time trying to figure a solution and it seems this could be caused by the CORS issue and so have added

```
"web-preferences": {
  "web-security": false
}
```

To my Electron BrowserWindow config but this has not helped.

Can anyone share a sample of doing a JQuery POST request in Electron. Be a big help. Thanks

Comment: If you want to send something from the browser window to the node server you don't need to do this over a post request. Could you describe a little more about, what you want to send via post.

Comment: @apxp they are the username, password and host values for a server I need the app to connect to and then return a JSON response